# how to find missing files from archives

Tags: linux, archiving

I need to help a friend archive his old data (around 200GB). I see that a lot of the files are already present in a newer archive he has but the newer archives is properly organized in directories. So I can't simply use `rsync`.

My question is how to easily get a list of only the files that are not present in the new archive.

For example:

```
$ files_not_present old_dir new_dir
file1
file2
...
```

Comment: other than writing your own script to do it, the only idea that comes to me is to use a duplicate checker like fslint, to generate a list of files you DON'T want to archive, and using --exclude in rsync. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/

Comment: Are there any files with the same name/path but are different, do they matter? Or are you only going by filenames?

Comment: I'm assuming files with same name are the same. Highly unlikely to be different in this case. Or if they are, then they are older and not needed.
I just finished a script to do the comparoson. Now going to see how much I really found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't look at this ugly hack below. If I ever have to do this again I'll update my gist to be more useful:
https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/4cda59f17c450f64bbd6

useless stuff below:

Ok, I used this approach if anybody needs it:

1. get a list of files in new and old archives:

   ```
   $ find new_dir -type f > arch.txt
   $ find old_dir -type f > arch_old.txt
   ```

   btw you can use `find -name ".?*" -prune -o -type f` to avoid hidden files
2. use this `ruby` script to get a list of files that are present in old archive nut not in the new one:

   ```
   org_arch = "arch.txt"
   to_arch = "arch_old.txt"

   # populate Hash with files under question to archive
   arch={}
   File.open(to_arch, "r") do |infile|
     while (line = infile.gets)
       arch[File.basename(line)] = line
     end
   end

   # remove from Hash what has already been archived
   File.open(org_arch, "r") do |infile|
     while (path = infile.gets)
       arch.delete(File.basename(path))
     end
   end

   #print files to be archived
   arch.each { |name,path|
     puts path
   }
   ```
3. See size of files you need to copy:

   ```
   cat to_arch.txt | xargs -d "\n" stat -c "%s" | awk '{size+=$1} END {print size}'
   ```

In my case I went from 200GB to around 80. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

let say your older archive folder is old_folder and new archive as new_folder

you can use the following line to compare two folders and to list the files in old_folder which is not available in the new_folder

```
for %%i in ("old_folder\*") do if not exist "new_folder\%%~nxi" echo(%%~i)>file.csv
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like a windows `cmd` command. I've put the `linux` tag on the question. Thanks for the answer but doesn't help me.

Comment: oops...Apologise for missing linux tag...Hope this would be a reference for windows users in future.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand files have the same names, yet they can be in different subfolders. You can start with the script, and develop it to Your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -d "$1" -a -d "$2" ] || exit
old_dir="$1"
new_dir="$2"
find "$old_dir/" -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort > oldlist.txt
find "$old_dir/" -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort > newlist.txt
diff oldlist.txt newlist.txt | grep '<'
```

Run this script:

```
./script.sh old_dir new_dir
```

The idea is to find all filenames (strip folder names with `basename`), sort the lists and compare them with `diff`. File list will be left in `oldlist.txt` and `newlist.txt` files.

Comment: this doesn't cover the case where same file has different PATH. I could have user `diff -r` if I didn't care.

Comment: @akostadinov, paths are removed from both listings (there should be no `/` symbols in both listings generated), so it should be no difference in what subfolder file is placed. Or do You mean something else?

Comment: I didn't notice that. But I don't end up with paths I need to copy over though, only names. This is something. Still I'm crafting a script to do what I need in ruby.